# Appending props in a child component to an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

In my parent component I have a form, I need the input of that form to pass to the child component where I need it to append to an API. I've been trying to do it as such:

```js
`https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?=firstName${this.props.name}`
```

but I keep getting this error: jQuery.Deferred exception: this.state.jokes.map is not a function TypeError: this.state.jokes.map is not a function

The map function does work when I don't add the props to the API.

Full code here:

Parent:

```js
class Input extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        value: ' ',
        selected: false
      }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState(
    {value: event.target.value}
    );
  }



  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState(
      {selected: true}
    )
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/mugen/images/b/b6/Chuck-norris.png/revision/latest?cb=20120615045306" alt="chuck"/>
          <form>
            <h1>Whats your name?</h1>
              <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </form>
            <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} id="submit">
              <Link to="/jokes">Submit</Link>
            </Button>
            {this.state.selected === true
              ?
            <Jokes name={this.state.value} />
              :
              null
              }
        </div>
      )
   }

  }
```

child:

```js
class Jokes extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {jokes: []}
    this.JokeList = this.JokeList.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.JokeList()
  }

  JokeList() {
    return $.getJSON(`https://api.icndb.com/jokes`)
      .then((data) =>{
        this.setState({ jokes: data.value })
        console.log(this.state.jokes)
      });
  }

  render(){
      const funnies = this.state.jokes.map((item, i) => {
        return <div id="quoteList">
               <h1 id="num" className="answers" key="id">{item.id}</h1>
                <h2 id="quote" className="answers" key="yoke">{item.joke}</h2>
              </div>
        })
    return(

        <div> { funnies } </div>

      )
  }
}
```

any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here... You can pass any props from parent to child though, and you can access them anywhere.

Comment: @paqash I rephrased it to be more specific about my issue

Comment: can you check `data.value` before you call `this.setState({ jokes: data.value })`

Comment: I suspect that this.state.jokes is not an array when this is happening.  You may want to start looking there.  It'll probably lead you to the answer.

Comment: @paqash I feel like I understand what you are getting at but what exactly do you mean by check?

Comment: He means whether or not `data.value` is array. If it's not an array - this is the error and you have to investigate why it's not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked what's happening.

When you request `https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?=firstName${this.props.name}` it's very possible to return only one record, because of filtering criterias.

**In that case the API returns an Object, instead of an Array with one element**. That's the reason you get the error:

> this.state.jokes.map is not a function

However, I tuned up your code to support the both cases, please check the example below. Here is what I did, once we have the response:

```
// Make sure the jokes are an Array, because of we iterate over them later.
let jokes = Array.isArray(data.value) ? data.value : [data.value];
this.setState({ jokes });
```

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        value: ' ',
        selected: false
      }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState(
    {value: event.target.value}
    );
  }



  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState(
      {selected: true}
    )
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/mugen/images/b/b6/Chuck-norris.png/revision/latest?cb=20120615045306" alt="chuck"/>
          <form>
            <h1>Whats your name?</h1>
              <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </form>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} id="submit" />
            {this.state.selected === true
              ?
            <Jokes name={this.state.value} />
              :
              null
              }
        </div>
      )
   }

  }
  
class Jokes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {jokes: []}
    this.JokeList = this.JokeList.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.JokeList()
  }

  JokeList() {
    return $.getJSON(`https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?=firstName${this.props.name}`)
      .then((data) =>{
        // Make sure the jokes are an Array, because of we iterate over them later.
        let jokes = Array.isArray(data.value) ? data.value : [data.value];
        this.setState({ jokes });
      });
  }

  render(){
      const funnies = this.state.jokes.map((item, i) => {
        return <div id="quoteList">
               <h1 id="num" className="answers" key="id">{item.id}</h1>
                <h2 id="quote" className="answers" key="yoke">{item.joke}</h2>
              </div>
        })
    return(

        <div> { funnies } </div>

      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Input />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```